# transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug Error

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, shopify, firebase-cloud-messaging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCtfP.png)
I'm using shopify SDK in my android project, everything is good before integrating the Firebase Cloud Messaging Library.
when i add the firebase gradle dependency and run the project, this error appear.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/actions/ReserveIntents.class

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'd suggest that you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question accordingly. If you don't then you will likely get adverse feedback.

Comment: Please provide more details .

Comment: @AhlemJarrar can you help me in this topic

Comment: @Osamadarabeh did you try to clean your project ? There is a problem in your dependency . Can you please share your gardle file

Comment: @Osamadarabeh share your gardle file to see if there a missing dependency

Comment: @AhlemJarrar Yes, i am tried this but no response,please look in gradle in the top of the question

Answer (score 0):

Remove Your Jar file from dependencies gardle.project  and run your project

> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

Hope that will help